# How to script a table into a nested element, print array without loops

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I am working on this JavaScript problem and I have very little experience with JavaScript, so please bear with me.

I have an array of objects, and my goal is to print **some (not all)** of it's contents into an HTML table. I do not have access to the HTML, and am only permitted to write JavaScript in the script element of the HTML file. My question is 2 parts:

1) How do I successfully target the  section for the JavaScript

2) How do I print the objects of the array without using a loop?

For example, the array may be

```
myArray = [ { color:"red",    number:"9",   city:"San Francisco",  shape:"circle" }, 
            { color:"blue",   number:"28",  city:"Oakland", shape:"square" },
            { color:"green",  number:"41",  city:"San Jose", shape:"rhombus" }, 
            { color:"yellow", number:"19",  city:"Sacramento", shape:"triangle" } ]
```

An example of the HTML of where I want to target my JavaScript to print the table

```
<section id="ThisSection">
    <table>
        <tbody> **HERE** </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

The code I want to use JavaScript to insert should evaluate to something like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>myArray[0].number</td>
    <td>myArray[0].shape</td>
</tr>

...

<tr>
    <td>myArray[3].number</td>
    <td>myArray[3].shape</td>
</tr>
```

What i was trying to do to target the HTML section was something like
`document.getElementById("ThisSection").getElementByTagName("tbody").outerHTML = "<tr><td>myArray[0].color</td></tr>";`

etc.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. And to reiterate, when i'm inserting tabled HTML data from the array, I'm not to use a loop. I was planning to try using map, or some other array function, but was unsure of which to use. Any thought about what would do the trick?

THANK YOU!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share your attempts

Comment: `myArray` is an object, not an array. Also, why avoid a loop?

Comment: Using `map` will actually loop through items in an array, so I guess what you meant to say is that you don't want to use a `for loop`? Also, that's an `object` and not an `array`, just like @VLAZ said.

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried document.getElementById("ThisSection").getElementByTagName("tbody").outerHTML = "<tr><td>myArray[0].color</td></tr>"; but it gives me an error

Comment: @VLAZ It is a school assignment and I was instructed to not use a loop. I don't know why, I think it would be easier if I were allowed to.

Comment: I realized the code for the array wasn't correct, and I just fixed it.